# Can we expect $\|fg\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d} )} \leq C \|f\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d})} \|g\|_{X(\mathbb R^d)}$ in Banach algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be the space of functions  on $\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d$ $(d\in \mathbb N),$  that is, $X=\{f:\mathbb R^{d}\times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C: f \text{is function} \}.$ Assume that $(X, \|\cdot\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d})})$ is a Banach algebra. Therefore, we have 
$\|fg\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d})} \leq C \|f\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d})} \|g\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d})}$
for all $f, g \in X.$

Let $G\in X $ so $G:\mathbb R^{d}\times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R: (x,y)\mapsto G(x,y)\in \mathbb R$
be a function. Define
$g(x,y)= G(x,x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^{d}.$  Roughly speaking $g$ is a function on $\mathbb R^d.$

> **Question**: Can we expect $\|fg\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d} )} \leq C \|f\|_{X(\mathbb R^{2d})} \|g\|_{X(\mathbb R^d)}$?  Specifically, is there any examples of Banach spaces $X-$ where one can expect this kind of scenario? (e.g., Sobolev spaces or so..)

**Side Thoughts**: Define $h:\mathbb R^{2d} \to \mathbb R$ such   $h(x,y)= h(x,x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^d.$ Can we say $\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} |h(x,y)| dx dy = \int_{\mathbb R^d} |h(x,x)| dx$?

Comment: What is exactly $X(\Bbb R^d)$ ?

Comment: @Delta-u: Thanks. $X(\mathbb R^d)= \{ g(x,x): g(x,y)\in X(\mathbb R^{2d})\}.$